# How can I physically cut a 4x6 photo into precisely 6 photos of dimension 2x2?

Tags: print-production, photography

I have a photo of dimension 2 inches x 2 inches. I wanted 6 copies of it, so I printed it as a [grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGHx8.png) of dimension 4 inches x 6 inches using some [program](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/130401/9282). How can I physically cut a 4x6 photo into precisely 6 photos of dimension 2x2?

Comment: Use a paper guillotine, or a craft knife and a ruler?

Comment: @Scott cutting the 6 pictures from https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGHx8.png

Comment: This is why we have bleed. If you want them all absolutely identical size/shape then you can do it in 3 cuts [as you have a single sheet you can stack them] - but that leaves you no bleed and may get an edge of one pic in its neighbour. To eliminate that you need 4 more cuts, one each edge… which of course now leaves all your images slightly smaller than you require. [Ex bindery guillotine operator ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks, good point, an additional cut for each edge (resulting in a picture slightly smaller than 2 inches, unless using bleed) seems necessary indeed. I guess that's why my former passport pictures were slightly smaller 2x2. (~1.9x1.9).

Comment: @Tetsujin the employees of the Walgreens I eventually went to indeed use bleed (2.2x2.2 photo then cut to 2x2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some tool (I don't know the name) at my local Walgreens in the United States that can cut a 2x2 pictures:

[image]

Product page: [Passport Cutter for USA photos - 2 x 2 Inch](https://www.pakor.com/passport-cutter-for-usa-photos-50x50mm) (libertyphotoproducts got renamed "Pakor").